# PySpark: Remove character-digit combination following a white space using Regex

Tags: regex, string, pyspark, character, data-cleaning

I have a column full of strings where some are like this: " Telefon T1", " Post P2, ... Now I would like to remove everything following the word. For example, Telefon T1 becomes simply Telefon. I tried the following code in various ways, but it keeps giving me elephon.

```
df = df.withColumn('mycolumn', regexp_replace('mycolumn', '[*[ ]?[A-Z]?\d$]'', ""))
```

This is not so much a pyspark question, but a regular expression question. So if you get this to work with a list replace "I will get it". Thank you

Comment: Try `regexp_replace('mycolumn', r'^\s*(\S+).*', r'\1')`

Comment: This returns 1 for every row.

Comment: Did you use `r'\1'` as replacement?

Comment: Well, try `regexp_extract('mycolumn', r'^\s*(\S+)', 1)`

Comment: I tried r'\1'. When I try regexp_extract('mycolumn', r'^\s*(\S+).*', 1) I am getting a Py4JException

Comment: It is not clear what regex syntax your environment follows. Try `regexp_replace('mycolumn', '^\\s*(\\S+).*', '$1')`. Or replace with `'\\1'`. The idea [is working](https://regex101.com/r/IQUyQK/1).

Comment: ok df= df.withColumn('mycolumn', regexp_replace('mycolumn',  '^\\s*(\\S+).*', '$1')) worked. It was indeed a syntax problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df = df.withColumn('mycolumn', regexp_replace('mycolumn', '^\\s*(\\S+).*', '$1'))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQUyQK/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): any 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `.*` - the rest of the string, 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The `$1` replaement backreference in the replacement pattern only keeps the Group 1 value in the result.